# Google thinks my search is automatied and won't let me search

Tags: google-search

[image: screen shot of Google not working]

I connect to the internet through a VPN service. Is there anything I can do to not receive this? I'm not doing anything suspicious and the first Google search I do yields this.

I trust Google enough that I don't mind them knowing my identity but I know of no way to exempt certain websites from VPN. The next time this happens (which isn't always) I'll try logging into my Google account.

Comment: I guess you want to search anonymously? I think you are not the only one on this specific VPN service doing that and google can not distinguish the users.

Answer (score 3):

Try searching over another VPN or with no VPN at all. This is probably a VPN provider with only a very few IP's, or the IP was uses by a bot before you got assigned to it.

Or you could try to log into your Google Account. (Which is probably not what you want, given your use of a VPN in the first place.)